Why are mixamo animations messed up after combining them?
I am currently working on a baseball animation and I wanted to combine two mixamo animations that I have downloaded (idle and stepout). For some reason, the movement of the arms from the stepout animation gets completely messed up. I first wanted to solve the problem manually, because I read that there might be a mistake with the rotation of the arms however the whole animation does not show up on the Graph Editor.



I am quite new to blender so i would appreciate it if someone could help me out.
Thanks in advance

That's not really a qestion we can answer here. I'd suggest you watch a few short tutorials on combining Mixamo animations, such as this, this or this one.

To me, the crossed arms look as if there are different rest positions (e.g. T-pose vs A-pose). Make sure you select the same rest position (e.g. T-pose) for both animations when you download them from Mixamo.

Thanks a lot @Blunder. Indeed it had something to do with the rest pose. After I set the rest position to a T-pose it finally worked out.
